# Environmental Entry - Java EE - Web.XML - Null Value Returned

Tags: jakarta-ee, web.xml, java-ee-7

I am trying to retrieve the value from an Environment Entry in a web.xml file in my Java EE Web application. I am using Netbeans with a Glassfish server...

Here is my web.xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app version="3.1" xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee"         
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_1.xsd">

<env-entry>
    <description>This example uses @Resource()</description>
    <env-entry-name>com.stuff.PasswordSessionBean/password</env-entry-name>
    <env-entry-type>java.lang.String</env-entry-type>
    <env-entry-value>SteveJobbs</env-entry-value>
</env-entry>

<servlet>
    <servlet-name>PasswordServlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>com.stuff.PasswordServlet</servlet-class> 
</servlet>

<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>PasswordServlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/PasswordServlet</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>

<session-config>
    <session-timeout>
        30
    </session-timeout>
</session-config>


</web-app>
```

Here is the corresponding bean that is to receive the value which is injected by the .

```
package com.stuff;

import javax.annotation.Resource;


/**
*
* @author me
*/

public class PasswordSessionBean {

@Resource() private String password;


    public String getPassword(){
        return password;
    }

}
```

Comment: Is the PasswordSessionBean instantiated as a managed bean? It is no EJB. So it would be interesting how the Servlet gets access to the PasswordSessionBean.

Comment: :D Interesting. Thank-you for the helpful reply @RobertPanzer How would you recommend I fix this code. The servlet currently gets access to this 'bean' by instantiating an instance and then calling the getter method (getPassword). Do I just need to add annotations such as `@Stateless` and 
`@LocalBean` to make it an EJB?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you instantiate the bean yourself you will not benefit from container services like dependency injection.

In your case where you have a servlet and want to inject the env-entry into a dependent POJO, simply let the container inject the POJO into your servlet.
So instead of calling new PasswordSessionBean() yourself add this to your servlet:

```
@Inject
private PasswordSessionBean passwordSessionBean;
...
public void doGet(....) {
    assertEquals(passwordSessionBean.getPassword(), "SteveJobbs");
}
```

Defining the PasswordSessionBean is also a valid alternative, but seems to be an overkill for just getting an env-entry injected.

Comment: Simply, using the `@Inject` tag and creating the reference to the bean and then calling the getter method on the reference works. I do not even need the extra method in your solution. Thank-you for the help. :) Also, it is sort of odd that I do not need to instantiate the `passwordSessionBean` reference with the `new` keyword or anything.

Comment: If I instantiate the `passwordSessionBean` object and then call the `getPassword()` method it returns `null` again. It is odd that calling the method simply on the `PasswordSessionBean` reference works in retrieving the injected value from the Environmental Entry. :)

Comment: Yes, that is the expected behavior. The env-entry is only injected into the bean if the container instantiates it. If you do it via new() no container-"magic" will apply;-)